# Primefaces: selecting rows from nested DataTables

Tags: jsf-2, groovy, datatable, primefaces, nested

I'm using Primefaces 3.4 and Groovy.  I created objects `Part` and `Attachment`:

```
class Part {
    Attachment selectedAttachment
    List<Attachment> attachments = []

    AttachmentDataModel getAttachmentModel() {
        return new AttachmentDataModel(attachments)
    }
}

class Attachment {
    String fileName
    String fileType
    String description
}
```

My view has nested DataTables like so:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{mybean.parts}" var="part" rendered="#{mybean.attachmentsFound}">
    <p:column>
        <p:dataTable 
            var="attachment"
            selectionMode="single"
            value="#{part.attachmentModel}"
            selection="#{part.selectedAttachment}"
            >
            <p:column headerText="File Name">
                #{attachment.fileName}
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="File Description" style="width: 200px">
                #{attachment.description}
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="File Type" style="width: 20px">
                #{attachment.fileType}
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

I want to be able to select one attachment per part.

**Problem:** Only the *first* part's `selectedAttachment` gets set to the *last* selected attachment!

**Question:** How can I enable each part instance to save its selected attachment?  Thanks for your time.

*Note: If I debug my AttachmentDataModel, I see `getRowData` hit for as many selections as I make.*

Comment: What should we know about your `AttachmentDataModel` class? Maybe you wanted to point to the `attachments` list in your nested dataTable?

Comment: If I use the "rowKey" method and change the inner DataTable's value to `#{part.attachments}`, the same problem still occurs

Answer (score 1):

I'm still looking for an answer, but I've found a workaround.  I changed my view to:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{mybean.parts}" var="part" rendered="#{mybean.attachmentsFound}">
    <p:column>
        <p:dataTable 
            var="attachment"
            selectionMode="single"
            value="#{part.attachmentModel}"
            selection="#{part.selectedAttachment}"
            >
            <!-- WORKAROUND -->
            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{mybean.onRowSelect}" />
            <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{mybean.onRowUnselect}" />
            <!-- /WORKAROUND -->
            <p:column headerText="File Name">
                #{attachment.fileName}
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="File Description" style="width: 200px">
                #{attachment.description}
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="File Type" style="width: 20px">
                #{attachment.fileType}
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Then, in my backing bean (mybean), I implemented `onRowSelect/onRowUnselect` to add/remove my selections from a map.  The attachment's id is the key and the attachment is the value.